# Python custom alertscript in zabbix doesn't work properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, zabbix, smpp, zabbix-custom-reports

I would like to set sending SMS notifications by python script, but I have one problem with this. I am trying according this manual https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/en/manual/config/notifications/media/script . The script does execute but it doesn't send values which I want, it sends the parameters that are set up on the Zabbix server. This is my script:

```
import logging
import sys
import pandas as pd



import smpplib.gsm
import smpplib.client
import smpplib.consts



hostname = sys.argv[1]

eventname = sys.argv[2]

severity = sys.argv[3]



#if you want to know what's happening
logging.basicConfig(level='DEBUG')



# Two parts, GSM default / UCS2, SMS with UDH
parts, encoding_flag, msg_type_flag = smpplib.gsm.make_parts(u'')



client = smpplib.client.Client('smpp server ip ', example port)



# Print when obtain message_id
client.set_message_sent_handler(
    lambda pdu: sys.stdout.write('sent {} {}\n'.format(pdu.sequence, pdu.message_id)))



# Handle delivery receipts (and any MO SMS)
def handle_deliver_sm(pdu):
        sys.stdout.write('delivered {}\n'.format(pdu.receipted_message_id))
        return 0 # cmd status for deliver_sm_resp



client.set_message_received_handler(lambda pdu: handle_deliver_sm(pdu))



client.connect()
client.bind_transceiver(system_id='Example', password='Example@2023')



for part in parts:
        # Use command-line arguments for destination phone number and message content
        dest_phone = sys.argv[0]
        short_message = "{}: {}".format(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])

        pdu = client.send_message(
            source_addr_ton=smpplib.consts.SMPP_TON_ALNUM,
            source_addr_npi=smpplib.consts.SMPP_NPI_UNK,
            # Make sure it is a byte string, not unicode:
            source_addr='27840001019',



            dest_addr_ton=smpplib.consts.SMPP_TON_INTL,
            dest_addr_npi=smpplib.consts.SMPP_NPI_ISDN,
            # Make sure these two params are byte strings, not unicode:
            destination_addr=dest_phone,
            short_message=short_message,



            data_coding=encoding_flag,
            esm_class=msg_type_flag,
            registered_delivery=True,
        )
        print(pdu.sequence)



# Enters a loop, waiting for incoming PDUs
client.listen()
```

In zabbix settings I have added these parmeters:

```
{HOST.NAME}
{ACTION.ID}
{ALERT.SENDTO}
{ALERT.SUBJECT}
{EVENT.SEVERITY}
```

Notificiations which have been sent from zabbix don't contain values only parameter names. Notificiations look like this:

```
{HOST.NAME},{EVENT.NAME},{EVENT.SEVERITY}
```

Can someone please help find the problem in my code?

I tried implementing cli arguments on my script so that I when I run the script I can pass the arguments but I still get the Zabbix Parameters as an SMS instead of the actual IP for example

Comment: Are you passing those parameters on the command line and if so, what is an example of that. Perhaps what python sees is those exact strings not the resolution of them as environment parameters

Comment: @JonSG I am passing the parameters on the command line. An example of that is python3 script.py 'Linux Server' 'High CPU Usage' 'Average', I even tried passing the parameters and I still get the same output.